# disable ionic http request cache in ios

Tags: ios, angular, caching, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have made a program with ionic framework (Ionic 3). 
I am using `import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';`
for making http request. 
after building and running project in android and Ios, for making http call, it used from cache, and nothing was new, so I installed this plugin: `cordova-disable-http-cache`
after that , the cache problem is ok and disable in android, but in ios there is problem again and it is reading from cache! how can I totally disable cache in ionic for ios

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? can you share you actual code?